# Re-initialize a NSMutableString object

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I have something like this

```
NSMutableString *eng = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Stack"];
[eng appendString:@"overflow"];
```

Now I want to re-initialize the object "eng" to contain nothing, i.e, simply @""

I'm confused among the options I have. Please suggest among any of these, whichever is a good practice:

```
[eng init];
```

or

```
[eng initWithString:@""];
```

or

```
[eng setString:@""];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[eng setString:@""]` as that means the same `NSMutableString` instance is used and only its internal content is changed.

You cannot use `initXxx` unless you are willing to replace the current string instance with a new instance:

```
eng = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

There is also `[NSMutableString deleteCharactersInRange:]` to consider as well.

However at the end of the day it probably makes very little difference which of these methods is used.

Comment: Thanks for such a fast and well defined reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using third option:

```
[eng setString:@""];
```

In this case you still work with the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `setString` instead of `[[NSMutableString alloc] init];`

Although both work, the former just simply changes the value to a blank string.